# Unable to run application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, process

I'm testing some code which starts a process, calling an application's .exe file.

When opening it programmatically, I get the following error:

[image]

When I try loading it through the command prompt console, if I first `cd` to the parent directory, and then call the .exe, it works fine.  Thus, I am suspecting that it is due to the parent directory.

This is my code:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Test\\";
process.StartInfo.FileName = "Test.EXE";
process.Start();
```

I seem to be setting the parent directory - what else can I do?

Comment: If an Exe is loading properly then it might be possible that the exe you have opened causing this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested the exact code you posted here and it worked fine with me here :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process myProc = new Process();
    myProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\";
    myProc.StartInfo.FileName = "Chat APP.exe";
    myProc.Start();
}
```

so consider checking your system , privacy settings , permissions .. etc .

Answer (score 1):

The working directory is **not** the directory where the executable is located. It's the directory the executable considers its current directory.

Eg. all console commands reside somewhere below the Windows directory yet their working directory is whichever directory is current in the command line.

Your code uses a relative path name for the executable which means Windows will look for `Test.exe` in whatever directory is the current (working) directory for your parent application.

To fix this, simply pass the full path to the executable in `StartInfo.FileName`.

Comment: It actually does load the application though. So it finds the .exe, loads it, and after the loading screen displays the error message that it cannot find the disk. I have also tried adding the full path in the filename, but the same thing happens.

Comment: Then the problem is in 'Test.exe'. You need to post the relevant code and error message. Add logging and try to debug `Test.exe` to see what actually crashes and why

Answer (score 0):

You can also start the process directly by passing path as:

```
Process.Start("C:\\Test.exe");
```

Apparently there is nothing wrong with your code. To sole this problem go through these links:

http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/please-insert-a-disk-into-drive-device-harddisk-dr1-error-when-starting-a-program.162902/

http://www.fixya.com/support/t6556978-correct_device_harddisk1_dr7_problem

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2e3d2e68-a4e7-49b7-9d70-7b70c166a1c9/how-to-find-out-which-hdd-is-deviceharddiskdr-